# To detect dynamic loading of Frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

[image: Frame design]

I am working with such kind of frame design. Consider this image as brief overview of more complex design.

I am recursively iterating each frame, so as to add event listeners to it.
For the very first `$(window).load()` , I am able to add listeners successfully.

But the real trick is;
Frame 2.1 is navigationFrame whereas Frame 2.2 is detailFrame.
As name suggests whenever we click any link of 2.1, Frame 2.2 is loaded again.
Due to this, it looses listeners attached.
Since new frame is loaded, I can't keep track of newly loaded frame.

Though I've tried

```
element.onunload = function(){
    #add listeners recursively using element.parent
}
//where element is of type window
//created using 
/*for(var i=0;i<window.frames.length;i++){
   var element = window.frames[i];
}
*/
```

I've also tried `('frame').load`, but didn't work.

I cant use #frameID since this work is generic to any web application (whether or not it use frame.)

Please suggest me any way to deal this kind of situation.

Comment: Frameset has been deprecated quite awhile ago. You really shouldn't be using it now.

Comment: The listeners are added outside of the frame 2.2?

Comment: @Terry 
Actually , this is not my web page . I am supposed to deal with it as a part of browser add-on.

Comment: @Teemu
At very first time, listeners are added almost on complete web page.

Comment: But where? On the top-most page or somewhere else in that frame jungle? And as Terry said, framesets and frames are deprecated, prepare to create everything in HTML4 if you need a wide browser support for your app. F.e. IE9 doesn't show framesets and frames at all when having a HTML5 DTD, and many browsers which will show them, are downgrading to HTML4 automatically. This means the lack of the support for a lots of currently established APIs,  CSS and elements, and no ES6, only ES5 JavaScript.

Comment: @Teemu
So this is a WAS application. Created long back ago, since some people are still using this, I want my browser add-on to work on this too.
I hope you're getting my problem.

Comment: If you just would answer the question ... Where are the listeners added, on which page?